# Суффиксы страдательных причастий

Tags: орфография, причастия

Учебник русского языка Г.Н.Г., 10-11 классы.

В каком ряду в обоих словах на месте пропуска пишется буква Е?

1) кле.. мый, стреля... мый

2) движ... мый, спряга... мый

3) гоня... мый, вид... мый

4) завис... мый, вид... мый

Какой ответ ожидается?

Я думаю, что предполагается 1).

Но клеИмый надо писать с И. Форма несколько надуманная, не употребляется практически. Но причастие образовано от глагола 2 спряжения. Значит, И.

Как решить задачу? Никак?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я думаю, что предполагается 1).

**Я думаю, что предполагался ответ 3).** Обратите внимание, что слово "видимый" дано в рядах 3 и 4. Думаю, что это какая-то ошибка, допущенная уже при подготовке издания. Здесь могло в оригинале быть какое-то слово с согласной перед "-емый". Таких слов совсем немного: "колышемый" и ещё около 10 слов на "-лемый".

Comment: Ставлю плюс не за соображение о возможной ошибке (оно напрашивается), а за вот это вот: *здесь могло в оригинале быть какое-то слово с согласной перед "-емый"*. Долго думал, почему именно такой вариант, с согласной перед сомнительной гласной, вы сочли достойным "оригинала". Когда понял, оценил. Да, именно этот вариант предпочтителен, поскольку вся система перечисления приобретает законченный вид.

Comment: Да бросьте...  Никаких двух "видимый" в ряде публикаций этого задания нет. В п. 3 там приводится пара "гоня...мый, **нена**вид...мый". См. https://www.google.ru/search?q=%221%29+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5..+%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9,+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F...+%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9++2%29+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6...+%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9,+%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0...+%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=FUywWszbIKuLmwWM_aewDA

Answer (score 2):

Несомненно, неверно: клеемый.
Но некоторые говорят, что и *клеимый* не существует.

> [Вопрос № 206123](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%25)
>   как правильно: я жду звонок или я жду звонка? клеимый или клеемый?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Предпочтительно: *жду звонка*. Страдательное причастие настоящего времени от глагола *клеить* не образуется.

Как бы то ни было, верный ответ: ни в каком (ряду).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то "решение" (вернее сказать "ответ") ***ни в каком*** - тоже ответ, и этот ответ правильный.

Но в данном случае повтор слова в 3-й и 4-й парах действительно наводит на мысль о технической ошибке в формулировке задания.

Answer (score 1):

В полной парадигме Зализняка есть форма **клеимый.**

http://dicipedia.com/dic-ru-ru-para-term-26576.htm

Поэтому ответ: варианта с двумя буквами ***Е*** нет.

Ошибку можно сделать в словах двигать – ***движимый*** (*ИМ* как искл.) и клеить – ***клеимый*** (суффикс *И*  в глаголе ***клеить*** рекомендуется запомнить и правильно выбрать 2-е спряжение: клеит –  клеимый).

Comment: Видел мнение, что у Зализняка подход формальный, он приводит даже те формы, которых нет в словарях.

Comment: В словарях не приводятся все формы. А форма "клеимый"  теоретически может существовать, но практически не используется, так как заменяется формами "склеиваемый, "приклеиваемый", например: приклеиваемые (клеимые)  панели надо предварительно обработать.

Answer (score 1):

Увидел ответ **Jasmin** и комментарий к нему **М_Г**:

> Видел мнение, что у Зализняка подход формальный, он приводит даже те
>   формы, которых нет в словарях.

Выскажу своё мнение: НИКАКОГО ОТНОШЕНИЯ ЗАЛИЗНЯК к словарю, на который ссылается в своём ответе  **Jasmin**, НЕ ИМЕЕТ.

А если бы имел, то правильным ответом на поставленный в задании вопрос было бы указание на вариант "2":

***движЕмый, спрягаЕмый.***

Именно написание с ***Е***  (**дви́жемый**) выбрано в этом сетевом словаре в т. наз."Полной акцентуированной парадигме по А. А. Зализняку" для страдательного причастия настоящего времени для одного из значений глагола [***двигать***](http://dicipedia.com/dic-ru-ru-para-term-14370.htm). Зализняк же в своём словаре такую форму причастия не приводит. И потому вариант "2" можно исключить из числа правильных.

А вот вариант "1"… Но об этом потом.